# Listen to Salesforce Record Update Event in AppExchange Product

Tags: apex, appexchange, platform-event, change-data-capture, pushtopic

- Appexchange product has a push topic for example : [Select Id,Name From Account]
- When account update where name is "xyz", I want to capture that event in app exchange product and fire a action based on it.

To my understand : If i subcribe to this push topic from work bench i can see all the change.

But From Appexchange level : from apex how do i listen to this and perform certain action?

Comment: Why can't you just use a normal Apex trigger?

Comment: Apex Trigger wont serve the purpose